# Context on the theory of category theory

Tags: logic, category-theory, propositional-calculus

In first-order logic, one has a way of constructing all sentences out of some logical symbols, as well as function and relation symbols pertaining to a special kind of signature one is in.

Now in the book of Mac Lane on category theory, there is a similar construction, where the atomic statements (instead of only being things like equality over a single structure) involve also things like the domain of an arrow, where there are both objects and arrows, for instance.

I would like to ask whether there is some widely used general construction that generalises both.

Comment: The theory of categories can be formalized in a [2-sorted first-order language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-many-sorted/) with a sort for objects and a sort for arrows. You also have to either allow a partial function for composition, or encode composition as a ternary relation symbol for the graph of composition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alex says in the comments, you can use two-sorted first order logic for this, with a sort for objects and a sort for morphisms.

But actually this is technically unnecessary, and (small) categories can be axiomatized in ordinary first-order logic using morphisms only. The signature involves a set $A$ (the set of all morphisms), two unary functions $s, t : A \to A$ sending a morphism $f : c \to d$ to the identity morphism of its source $\text{id}_c$ and its target $\text{id}_d$ respectively, and a ternary relation $\circ \subset A \times A \times A$ consisting of the tuples $(f, g, f \circ g)$ describing composition, subject to various axioms, e.g. that for every tuple $(f, g, f \circ g)$ we must have

$$s(f \circ g) = s(g), t(f \circ g) = t(f), t(g) = s(f).$$

Identity morphisms, or equivalently objects, can be identified as those morphisms satisfying $s(i) = t(i) = i$ and that's how we state the identity axioms for composition.

However, you might find this a little contrived. The two-sorted theory is the more natural and straightforward thing to do and readily generalizes to a definition of an [internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) in a category with pullbacks (which are needed to describe composition).

Comment: Actually, I like not to burden myself with the additional technicality of having all my objects and morphisms be in one set, ie. I quite like large categories, because they really do give the totality of all objects that are supposed to be in the category. This already starts in the category of sets, where the ordinals alone get you out of any universe which is a set.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but I think for myself I'll be going with many-sorted logic, not least because it seems to me that for an internal category one would also need some underlying category wherein one has one's "category objects", and I imagine this underlying category would then be something like Set, imposing upon us a universe.

Comment: Or does one use classes and class functions? To me, this honestly gets a bit haskelly.

Comment: @Cloudscape: if you want to axiomatize not-necessarily-small categories then yes, you need to talk about classes and class functions. You can check out some details on the necessary amount of set theory to do this sort of thing here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279